# How to make array values variable

Tags: php, for-loop

```
$value = array('apple', 'mango', 'paron', continue);
```

Suppose i have 3 value in my $value array which i can easily get

```
count(array_filter($value))
```

which will return the values of that array which in this case 3.

Now i want to search something from database based on those values.

Like - in the name section i want to serch the "names".

So first it should search for "apple" in the name section than it should search for "mango" and than "paron".

```
$params = array();
$params['index'] = 'myIndex';
$params['type'] = 'myType';
$params['body']['query']['bool']['should'] = array(
    array('match' => array('name' => $value[i])),
);

$result = $client->search($params);
```

When there is no value left it should stop searching.

So how can i write this kind of method, anyone have an idea of that.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: `SELECT <column name> from <table name> WHERE VALUES IN (implode(',',$value))`

Comment: syntax error in 3... 2... 1...

Comment: First of all, please show us the code you have tried so far on that subject. Then, @A-2-A your suggestion may leave opening for sql injection, since you're passing raw variables to sql string AND the values are out of parenthesis AND are not quoted.

Comment: @A-2-A You have to assume that `continue` is just a placeholder to do that, tho https://3v4l.org/B9KiR

Comment: @Machavity what i understand that `continue` means some more values are there in the array and he shows only three here for simplifying his question. May be i am not correct I can't say.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('HOST','USER', 'PASSWORD', 'DBNAME');
$value = array('apple', 'mango', 'paron');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WERE name=?;");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$fruit);

for($i=0; $i < count($value); $i++){
$fruit = $value[$i];
$stmt->execute();
if($res = $stmt->get_result()){
while($row = $res->fetch()){
print_r($row);
}
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
}
}
```

Comment: Why should OP try this way?